# how to handle test Report aggregation in TFS

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager, e2e-testing

I'm currently trying to find out how I can handle all the different test reports I get from my delivery pipeline. I have lots of reports from different test cases such as E2E (Protractor), Unit-Tests (Karma) etc. Is there a tool which I can use to aggregate my reports? I want to have one report which consolidate all my different reports and sort them via build id. 
Can I use Microsoft Test Manager for this? 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All of this data in TFS is loaded into a data warehouse and cube. You can then connect Excel to this and create reports or you can create reports in reporting services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx

There are a bunch of out of the box reports and you can create anything that you want. If you don't have the data warehouse and cube then you may need to configure it as it was optional.

http://nakedalm.com/integrate-reporting-and-analyses-services-with-team-foundation-server-2013/

Comment: is there a way to script/automate the integration of my reports into the data warehouse?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question? The integration is provided by TFS and is outy of the box.